# How do I create a function to check if a string only consists of A-Z , 0-9

Tags: xquery

Is there any way to check in Xquery (A Xquery function) if an input string has only characters A-Z or numbers 0-9 and no other characters.
for example if the string is ABZ10 the function should return true and if the input string is 5& 123x it returns a false.
I am able to do it in java by simply using following.

```
inputstring.matches("^[0-9A-Z]+$"))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
matches($vYourString, '^[A-Z0-9]+$')
```